# LARAVEL: how to send Email data from view to controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, materialize

I need to send email But Not getting email address in `userController`

from **add.blade.php** to **userController@add.php**

this is the code of **add.blade.php** file:

```
<div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal--blocks">
                    <div class="small--heading">
                        <form class="col s12">
                            <div class="input-field">
                                <div class="chips"></div>
           
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field-btn">
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="button" id="send_email">Send Email</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is the scripte in **add.blade.php** file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="css/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

 $(document).on('click', '#send_email', function(){
    var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

    var instance = M.Chips.getInstance($('.chips'));
    var email_address = instance.chipsData;
    alert(instance);
    alert(email_address);
//    alert(email_address);
    $.each(email_address, function(i, value){
    if (!testEmail.test(value.tag)){
    instance.deleteChip(i);
    }
    });
    $("#send_email").text("processing..");
    $("#send_email").prop('disabled', true);
    var artist_id = "{{$artist->artist_id}}";
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "{{url('/label/artist/weeklyreport/send')}}",
            method: "POST",
            data: { _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), email:email_address, artist_uuid:artist_id}
    });
    request.done(function(resp) {
    if (!resp.error) {
    if (resp.result.status){
    $("#modalEmailTemplates").modal('close');
    $("#response_weekly_report").show();
    }
    }
    });
    });
```

**userController.php** file :

```
    public function weeklyreportSend(Request $request) {
        dd($request->email);die;
//        $email = 'shiyalparesh25@gmail.';
        $post = [];
        $post['email'] = array_column($request->email, 'tag');
        $post['subject'] = Config::get('constant.REPLAY_NAME') . "- Weekly Report";
        $post['data'] = $this->get_weekly_report_data($request->artist_uuid);

        $result = Helper::sendMail($post, "weekly_report");

        return response()->json(['error' => false, 'result' => $result]);
    }
```

Problem :- i'm not getting email value in Controller.if any have problem like me Please Help

Comment: `dd($request->all());die;` may help.

Comment: not getting email There @MaggsWeb

Comment: Does the alert show the email address? What if you don't disable the email field

Comment: getting blank value in alert @GertB.